# Graph Admin Consent - Why/When to specify tenant

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

While reading the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service) about getting access without a user
i noticed that in Step 3, in order to get the token, you need to send a get request to the following endpoint:

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/adminconsent
```

or if the tenant is unkown to

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent
```

The results (redirects, confirmation of app rights, ...) are still the same.

My Question is:

- Why not use always `/common/adminconsent` instead of `/{tenant}/adminconsent`?
- And in what scenarios would it be recommended or needed to use `/{tenant}/adminconsent`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a tenant in order to restrict who can authenticate. If you provide a tenant id, only an Admin from that tenant would be able to consent to your application. Using `common` allows any Admin, from any tenant, to consent to your application.

In practice, you rarely need to specify a tenant.